# Use Go slice in C

Tags: c, go, cgo

I'm trying to build a go shared library with a function that returns a slice.
How can I use the slice from C code ?

```
package main

import "C"

type T struct {
    A C.int
    B *C.char
}

//export Test
func Test() []T {
    arr := make([]T, 0)
    arr = append(arr, T{C.int(1), C.CString("a")})
    arr = append(arr, T{C.int(2), C.CString("abc")})
    return arr
}

func main() {}
```

`go build -o lib.so -buildmode=c-shared main.go`

I now have a `lib.so` and a `lib.h`

What would be the C code to print the values of the array ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lib.h"

typedef struct {
  int   A;
  char* B;
} T;

int main() {
  GoSlice a = Test();
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    printf("%s\n", ((T *)a.data)[i].B);
  }
}
```

`gcc -o main main.c ./lib.so`

Comment: Don't return a Go slice to C code, since C code doesn't know what a Go slice is. Give it a an array pointer just like you would in plain C.

Comment: I tried a lot of different things. I cannot figure it out.
I know I should not return a slice, I should probably return an unsafe.Pointer or something similar. But I think it will be easier for other people to understand what I'm trying to do with this example.
If you have any example of how to do it, I would really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

To start, C doesn't know about the Go slice type, nor how to manipulate it, so you should return an array pointer just like you would in C.

You also can't allocate the slice in Go then return a pointer to the allocated memory without some way to keep it from being GC'ed. In this example it's probably simpler to just allocate the array in C.

```
p := C.malloc(2 * C.size_t(unsafe.Sizeof(T{})))

// convert the C pointer to a slice of `[]T` for convenient indexing
arr := unsafe.Slice((*T)(p), 2)
arr[0].A = C.int(1)
arr[0].B = C.CString("a")
arr[1].A = C.int(2)
arr[1].B = C.CString("abc")
```

You will also of course need to handle the array size, which you could do with by combining it into a struct like you did for strings, or accept a second pointer parameter to set to the return size.

Don't forget that since you are allocating the memory in C, you are also responsible for freeing it. This goes for both the `malloc` call, as well as for the `C.CString` arrays.

Comment: Why is it `(*[1 << 30]*T)(p)[:2:2]` and not `(*[1 << 30]T)(p)[:2:2]`? Wouldn't that give a slice of pointers rather than a slice of structs?

Comment: @Hermann: yes this is a slice of pointers. Both this and the original are contrived examples, and should be adapted to fix the actual data types being used.

Comment: Apparently, I struggle to understand the assignment semantics in go. With the example given, I would expect the slice to be filled with pointers. The structs seem to be allocated in go and prone to being garbage collected. I suspect that is something I need to account for when adapting the example. Is that correct?

Comment: @Hermann: I think you've got the idea, and that's a good point, the structs are Go values. This was a long time ago, but I probably hastily wrote the example to highlight `C.malloc` without as much regard for the rest (or maybe I copied it from something else?). I'll update it to something without go allocations, and use the newer `unsafe.Slice` too.