# How to pass a nested Struct or a Multidimensional Array from Go to C

Tags: c, go, multidimensional-array, struct, cgo

i have a problem/question about cgo.
I want to pass a nested Struct or a multidimensional Array from Go to C.

First of all the Code

```
struct rectangle  {
    int A;
    int B;
    int C
    int D;
};

struct recList{
    struct rectangle rectangles[2];
};

import "C"


//export  recMethod
func recMethod() C.struct_recList {

recs := getRectangles()

rectangle1 := C.struct_rectangle{}
rectangle1.A = recs[0].A
rectangle1.B = recs[0].B
rectangle1.C = recs[0].C
rectangle1.D = recs[0].D

rectangle2 := C.struct_rectangle{}
rectangle2.A = recs[1].A
rectangle2.B = recs[1].B
rectangle2.C = recs[1].C
rectangle2.D = recs[1].D


myRecList := C.struct_recList{}
myRecList[0] = rectangle1
myRecList[1] = rectangle1

return myRecList
}
```

I just created this Code as an Example for better understanding.
This Code should be working fine.

My Problem is that i dont know how big my actual Array in the recList-Struct should be because i only know it in runtime. (getRectangles())

Im creating a Lib out of this Go-Code so i can bind it in C.
In C i want to get access to the recList-Struct like

```
test = recMethod();
printf("%d", test.rectangles[0].A);
```

I hope i could explain myself good enough.

Comment: You pass an array through CGO exactly the same way to pass it within C, you allocate the memory as needed and communicate the length along with the array.

Comment: But how to do it especially in my case?
In my struct there is "struct rectangle rectangles[2];"
If i let it like this "struct rectangle rectangles[];" it wouldnt let me compile.

Comment: That's up to you. You can't do it with this exact code, because there's no place to store the array length. You could add it to the `recList` struct if you want. You are going to have a learn a little C in order to write C code -- CGO can't hide that.

Comment: Could you give me a little code snippet which shows how to do so?

Comment: maybe something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51525876/use-go-slice-in-c/51526388#51526388?